# What is the assumption of conservation of rest mass in gravitational collapse?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, black-holes, mass, gravitational-collapse

I have been reading up a paper on [gravitational collapse](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.141.1232), where a particular equation $$ 4\pi \rho R^2 b = 1 $$ means the assumption of conservation of rest mass. Here the spacetime interval is described by this line integral $$ ds^2 = a^2(\mu,t)c^2dt^2 - b^2(\mu,t)c^2d\mu^2 - R^2(\mu,t)c^2d\Omega^2$$ and $T^{1}_{1} = T^{2}_{2} = T^{3}_{3} = P$, $T^{0}_{0} = -\rho(c^2 + \epsilon)$
I'm not sure how the equation $ 4\pi \rho R^2 b = 1 $ came to be, can anyone explain?

Comment: On the first page it says: "We neglect pair production and annihilation,and the interaction of the fluid with external fields so that rest mass is conserved." Can you explain why this does not answer your question?

Comment: I meant how can I arrive at the same result, calculation-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the paper already mentions that they are using "$\mu$" as the rest mass between the point labelled and the center, which also appears in the context of metric tensor, the whole expression becomes quite trivial to evaulate
$$\frac{d m}{dt} = \frac{d \mu}{dt} = 0 \implies dm = d\mu$$

Rewriting the expression in terms of $T_{00}=\rho$
\begin{equation}\require{cancel}
\rho dV= d \mu\\
\\\
\\\
\rho\sqrt{b^2R^{4}\sin^2\theta} \cancel{d\mu} d\theta d\phi = \cancel{d\mu} \implies \rho (4\pi R^2 b) = 1
\end{equation}